# Correct preg_replace format

Tags: preg-replace

What is the correct preg_replace format to replace everything (including the brackets) between (xxxxxx).  Example have string (not long) link this: AAAAABBBBB (AAAAABBBBB) and all I want is AAAAABBBBB.  I need to use preg_replace as the string and it's string length changes.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understood your question right, but this should return the string insite the parentheses

```
$string = "CCCCC (AAAAABBBBB)";
return preg_replace("(.+\(|\))","",$string);
```

This regex will basically look for any string followed by ( and singular")" and replace them with "".